# What are the best practices to securely store/access SaaS customer data on Amazon S3?

Tags: security, amazon-s3, saas

To all those SaaS engineers/developers out there ...

I am building a SaaS product which will store customer data on S3. I wonder what is the best approach regarding security?

- Have a single IAM user with a bucket policy. That would be simple but data security is handled purely by the SaaS app. In case of a glitch, other users could have access to restricted material.
- What about creating an IAM user (via IAM REST API) for each new customer account and having object specific ACL for each stored object? More complex but it adds a layer of security in S3 as well.
- Any other way?

Also, to provide access to the material via the SaaS app. I plan to have each object 'readable name' replaced with a guid so that it cannot be easily guessed and use pre-signed urls with a time limit to see and download them. Is that a best practice? What time limit is considered safe and user-friendly?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never generate AWS IAM Users for "end-users" of your application (option 2). IAM grants permission to call AWS APIs and the end-users of your application should never need to call an API.

Information stored in Amazon S3 should be available to your SaaS application via standard methods:

- Create an **IAM Role** for your application
- Select the IAM Role when **launching** Amazon EC2 instances that run your application
- Any code running on the Amazon **EC2 instances that uses the AWS SDK will know how to automatically** access credentials via the [EC2 instance metadata service](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html)

If you wish to serve content from Amazon S3 directly to users of the application, generate [Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), that provide time-limited access to objects stored in S3 buckets. A 15-minute expiry duration could be a good trade-off between security and users who pause to take a phone call, but that timing is up to you.

Your S3 bucket **should not have a bucket policy** because all access will be via permissions granted to the IAM Role, or via pre-signed URLs.

The use of randomized GUIDs as filenames is **irrelevant** because you will have proper security rather than obfuscation.

Comment: Thanks John! I am hosting on Heroku, so I simply need the S3 storage. Good point for the API Access. However, I would not have shared the IAM user with the customer. It would have been internal to the app. Regarding bucket policy, I am a little bit confused by the answer. I need to grant bucket access to the IAM user. If I grant bucket access to him, he will be able to put objects and provide pre-signed access to the customer. This way, I don't need to create more ACL for the objects. Finally, I guess that I was wrongfully thinking that presigned provided time limited access to all objects.

Comment: An Amazon S3 bucket policy is typically used to grant access for **all users**. If you wish to grant access to a specific user, put the policy on the IAM user themselves (rather than the S3 bucket).

Answer (score 1):

Recently AWS created a blog post about how to `Partitioning and Isolating Multi-Tenant SaaS Data with Amazon S3` which I believe addresses you question very well.

Here is the link:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/partitioning-and-isolating-multi-tenant-saas-data-with-amazon-s3/?ck_subscriber_id=553485768